# [JAVA]Send a hyperlink on a webpage using selenium

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to update a table on webpage with a hyperlink. for instance the text on table will show just "Google" as a hyperlink to http://www.google.com.

Is it possible to send a link directly to java.

I tried something like sending a href=\""+myLink+"\">"+myText +/a on the page but it printed the exact same string instead of showing a hyperlink.

Comment: Share you code trial please.

Comment: I don't understand your question. What do yo mean by "update a table" and "sending a link to Java"? Selenium is mainly for controlling the browser instead of a real user, and extracting data from a webpage, not for updating a webpage. Selenium also allows you to execute JavaScript on a webpage which may be what you're looking for, but that's not clear from your question. What are you trying to achieve by updating that link on the table?